# Setting custom statusline for help window

Tags: split, statusline, help-system

I've been trying to set a custom statusline for help files. I tried:

```
set statusline=%!StatusLine()
function! StatusLine()
    if &ft == 'help'
        let b:status = "%#error#[HELP]%*"
    else
        let b:status = "my usual statusline"
    endif
    return b:status
endfunction
```

but when a help window is open, both statuslines become `[HELP]` when that window is in focus, and my usual statusline when the main file is open. I tried using `setlocal statusline=%!StatusLine()`, but then nothing gets set for the help file and the main file statusline still becomes `[HELP]`.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [`:h status-line`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/windows.txt.html#status-line):

> This option can be local to the window, so that you can have a different
>   status line in each window.

As ljden pointed out, you must use a local status line otherwise it is set for all buffers:

```
set statusline=%!StatusLine()
function! StatusLine()
    if &ft == 'help'
        let l:status = "%#error#[HELP]%*"
    else
        let l:status = "my usual statusline"
    endif
    let &l:statusline = l:status
endfunction
```

However it might be easier to just add this to `~/.vim/ftplugin/help.vim`:

```
setlocal statusline=%#error#[HELP]%*
```

Comment: Only just got comment privilege otherwise would jave said before, I tried your first suggestion and it doesnt quite work as expected. When I add it to my vimrc and opened vim and then a help file, the statusline changed from `my usual statusline` to `0`. Not sure why as I'm a little unfamiliar with this syntax and vimrc in general (still newish to it) but yeah didnt seem to work

Comment: The first method is kind of hacky, it should return a value but does not, hence the 0. This works on my machine though. The `ftplugin` method overrides any previously set statusline the same way an `augroup` + `autocmd` does. Finally another trick would be to return an expression to be evaluated in the context of each statusline: `set statusline=%{MyStatusLine()}`. There is interesting examples at the end of [`:h stl`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27statusline%27).

Answer (score 3):

EDIT: SO I tested it out a little more this morning and had a bit of a dig. Your main issue was trying to do it all in the one function, I don't think this will work sorry. It also [looks like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20821185/vimrc-checking-ft-doesnt-work-unless-filetype-detect-ran-1st) you may have an issue with the filetype detection with the new buffer load. It appears `if &ft == 'help'` can be a little problematic, and it's probably better to use an `autocmd`, which should be wrapped in an `augroup` - from `:help augroup-delete` (can test out your new status line while you have a read!)

> This prevents having the autocommands defined twice (e.g., after sourcing the .vimrc file again).

I've re-written the code so it follows OP's example more closely

```
" Default statusline
set statusline=%!StatusLine()
function! StatusLine()
    let b:status =  "my usual statusline"
    return b:status    
endfunction
" Override default statusline if help file
aug HelpStatusLine
    au!
    au FileType help setlocal statusline=%!LocalStatusLine()
aug END
function! LocalStatusLine()
    let b:status = "%#error#[HELP]%*"
    return b:status
endfunction
```